# I need to put the Activity "On Pause" in order for the search function to work

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am using an Edit Text to include a search to filter the data of my RecyclerView, and even though it works, I need to put the activity on pause and the resume it, in order for it to make the changes (Ex. toopen another activity and then go back to the RecyclerView).

I don't know why this is happening and would like to use the right approach to solve this.

The activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);
        searchText = findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        buttonAddProduct = findViewById(R.id.button_add_product);
        buttonAddProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Make add product button visible for this activity
        buttonAddProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AdminControl.this, SingleProductAdmin.class));
            }
        });


        setUpProductsView(productRef);

        //Search view
        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text after changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (s.toString() != null) {

                    //create query
                    Query searchQuery = productRef.orderBy("name")
                            .startAt(s.toString())
                            .endAt(s.toString() + "\uf8ff");

                    //build activity based on that query
                    setUpProductsView(searchQuery);
                } else {
                    setUpProductsView(productRef);
                }
            }
        });


    }


    private void setUpProductsView(Query query) {
        //set view
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Product> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()
                .setQuery(query, Product.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new ProductAdapter(options, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I am not sure your question is clear enough. Can you give more context? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I am trying to perform an instant search, but if I type something (the name and of a product or a letter) I can't get any results or the activity doesn't perform any search until the Activity on pause and resume it again (example: I type "G" and open another activity and then go back to the Recycler view in order to see the results)